# Linux - How to remove entries from /proc/devices

Tags: linux, module, kernel, driver

I tried to write a simple character device driver, now, even when I called `unregister_chrdev_region` I still see my devices left in `/proc/devices`, like this:

```
248 chardev
249 chardev
250 chardev
```

Now I cannot insert any module, everytime I use `insmod` the shell tells me:

```
Error: could not insert module test.ko: Device or resource busy
```

I'm asking **how to remove** these registered devices from `/proc/devices`. I already used `rmmod`, and already `rm` any `chardev` from `/dev`. But they are still there, stuck in `/proc/devices`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the correct device major number when calling `unregister_chrdev_region`. I had a similar issue where I was overriding my global `dev_major` variable with a local scope variable of the same name, causing me to pass 0 to `unregister_chrdev_region`.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance, I've been away from linux kernel things for decades, can't even remember the scenario when I wrote this question. Just think an answer is needed, and yours maybe the closest. Thanks for your time, guys.

Comment: I have been calling `unregister_chrdev_region` but still it is not getting removed!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. This works fine. The header file is ommitted, where all file opeartions are implemented.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include "my_char_device.h"

MODULE_AUTHOR("alakesh");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Char Device");


static int r_init(void);
static void r_cleanup(void);

module_init(r_init);
module_exit(r_cleanup);


static struct cdev r_cdev;
static int r_init(void)
{
    int ret=0;
    dev_t dev;
    dev = MKDEV(222,0);
    if (register_chrdev_region(dev, 2, "alakesh")){
        goto error;
    }
    cdev_init(&r_cdev, &my_fops);
    ret = cdev_add(&r_cdev, dev, 2);
    return 0;
error:
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev, 2);
    return 0;
}


static void r_cleanup(void)
{
    cdev_del(&r_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(222,0),2);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem when I was programming my initial char deriver program. Issue is due to passing invalid major number in the function unregister_chrdev_region(dev_t div_major, unsigned count).

I added a piece of code in exit routine to remove the device files which are not removed from the /proc/devices.

```
lets say these are the devices we need to remove.
248 chardev
249 chardev
250 chardev

static void r_cleanup(void)
{
    cdev_del(&r_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(222,0),2);

    //My code changes. 
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(248,0), 1);
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(249,0), 1);
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(250,0), 1);

    return;
}
```

The above reference code change in exit routine will remove the char devices with major number 248, 249 and 250.